# ios - sqlite prepare statement

Tags: ios, xcode, sqlite

I am trying to read data from a sqlite database in an ios app. When I run the app, it is able to open the database but in the log file it shows the message - "Problem with the prepare statement". I don't know what is wrong with my prepare statement Here's my code -

```
-(NSString *)dataFilePath{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    return [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:kFilename];
}
```

In the **viewDidLoad** I have -

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    myarray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    sqlite3 *database;
    if(sqlite3_open([[self dataFilePath]UTF8String], &database)!=SQLITE_OK){
        sqlite3_close(database);
       NSAssert(0, @"Failed to open database");
    }

    const char *createSQL = @"SELECT ID, TITLE FROM FIRST ORDER BY TITLE;"; //first is the table in the database
    sqlite3_stmt *sqlStmt;
    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, [createSQL UTF8String], -1, &sqlStmt, nil)!=SQLITE_OK){
        NSLog(@"Problem with prepare statement"); //this is where the code gets stuck and I don't know why
    }else{

        while(sqlite3_step(sqlStmt)==SQLITE_ROW){
            NSInteger number = sqlite3_column_int(sqlStmt, 0);
            NSString *title = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(sqlStmt, 1)];
            [myarray addObject:title];
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(sqlStmt);
    }
    sqlite3_close(database);
}
```

Comment: probably the path to DB is not correct, In my case I have added an existing sqlite DB to the project and in that case it will be stored in `AppName.app` folder not under `Documents`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your prepare statement fails, rather than just reporting "Problem with prepare statement", try retrieving the error message, e.g.,

```
NSLog(@"%s Prepare failure '%s' (%1d)", __FUNCTION__, sqlite3_errmsg(database), sqlite3_errcode(database));
```

This might give you a better indication of the problem.

A problem I've seen in the past is that the database might not be found (because it wasn't included in the bundle, typo in the name, etc.) but the standard `sqlite3_open` function will create it if it's not there, and thus the `sqlite3_open` will succeed, but the table in question won't be found in the blank, newly created database. Better than `sqlite3_open` would be:

```
sqlite3 *database;
if (sqlite3_open_v2([[self dataFilePath] UTF8String], &database, SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE, NULL) != SQLITE_OK) {
    sqlite3_close(database); // not sure you need to close if the open failed
    NSAssert(0, @"Failed to open database");
}
```

That way you get a warning if the database is not found. But if you've done `sqlite3_open` already, you might have a blank database, so you might want to reset your simulator and/or remove the app from your device, before trying it with `sqlite3_open_v2`.

Comment: As an aside, I'd be wary about using table names (or field names) that are the same as SQL reserved words (such as `FIRST`). I doubt this is the issue, but at best, it's confusing.

Comment: After I used the updated sqlite3_open_v2 statement and cleaned up the simulator, its failing at the NSAssert statement and giving the message - Failed to open the database. Why is it not opening the database, I don't know

Comment: @AshishAgarwal Is the database part of your bundle? Open up the target settings, click on the "Build Phases" tab, and expand "Copy Bundle Resources" and make sure your database is the list of files to include. You can also confirm what is included in your app by opening the simulator's folders in Finder, e.g. "~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator" (if you're not seeing the Library folder, unhide it by going to terminal and issuing the command "`chflags nohidden ~/Library`").

Comment: I can see the database file when I expand "Copy Bundle Resources" in the "Build Phases" tab. But I can't find the file anywhere when I go to "~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.0/Library"

Comment: @AshishAgarwal Your `dataFilePath` suggests that it would be in the documents folder (which it obviously won't be until you copy it there). If you want to find it in your bundle as via Finder, find your app, control-click on it, select "Show Package Contents". If you want to find it via your code, it's `[[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:kFilename];`. You can either open it there, or better, have your program copy it to the `Documents` folder you reference in your `dataFilePath` method.

Comment: I was successfully able to copy the database into the documents folder programatically and I'm now able to open the database. But the code is once again failing to prepare. The error message I'm getting now is - Prepare failure 'near "ååQ": syntax error' (1)

Comment: @AshishAgarwal I assume you noticed that `createSQL` should have been declared as a `NSString` (because you're setting it to `@"..."`), and then the `UTF8String` will convert that to a `const char *` for you.

Answer (score 1):

Several things you can try.

1. Clean your app, Remove from simulator or device & try installing a fresh copy again and see if it works.
2. Open your DB in Terminal & try to run your sql statement at there. Check wether you are getting desired output.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the nil to NULL. Also, try defining the SQL statement as a const char.

```
....

const char *sql = "SELECT ID, TITLE FROM FIRST ORDER BY TITLE";
sqlite3_stmt *sqlStmt;

if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &sqlStmt, NULL)!=SQLITE_OK){

....
```

Comment: same problem, nothing happened